# Rails with Cloud66 and DigitalOcean deploy without affecting currently running sidekiq process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, sidekiq

I have created Rails(version 5) application with Ruby(2.4.1). I am using DigitalOcean instance and Cloud66 for deployment process. I am using Sidekiq for background processing. My every deployment kills some long running process from sidekiq and this doesn't retried. Every task in sidekiq is more important, so I want to deploy without affecting those jobs. Is there any way to deploy without affecting currently running process in sidekiq?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution.

I have used pre deploy hooks to send TSTP before start deployment and then send TERM to gracefully shutdown sidekiq process. So before starting deployment all sidekiq process will be killed gracefully and those jobs will be executed using sidekiq process created by latest deployment.

**TSTP** - This will stop taking upcoming task from redis.

Usage: e.g) `kill -TSTP <sidekiq-processid>`

<>**TERM** - This will terminate the process within the time mentioned in `-t timeout_value` option, suppose running jobs are not completed then sidekiq process will be terminated and again the job will be pushed into the queue and the job will be executed again with same arguments.

**Note: Use this method when there is no issue in executing the same task again from the start.**

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq supports graceful shutdown, which means it gives for the running jobs some time finish. By default, I believe it is something like 30 seconds.

You can adjust that waiting time in `config/sidekiq.yml`:

```
:timeout: 120
```

More info about that: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals